# Hillel's or Shammai's?

Tags: talmud-bavli

In this Talmudic passage, which opinion prevails on the law according to the Talmud, Hillel's or Shammai's?

> "Rav Ḥisda raised an objection from a mishna (Nidda 64b). With regard
> to a young girl whose time to see the flow of menstrual blood has not
> arrived, as she has not yet reached puberty, and she married, Beit
> Shammai say: One gives her four nights during which she may engage in
> intercourse, as any blood is attributed to the ruptured hymen. Beit
> Hillel say: There is no limit. Rather, any blood she sees is
> attributed to the ruptured hymen until the wound heals."([Ketubot
> 6a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.6a.7?lang=bi))

Comment: Related:https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77932/when-is-the-halacha-like-bais-shammai-and-not-bais-hillel

Comment: I read the post, but it didn't answer my specific question. Maimonides (Hilchot Issurei Biah 5:19) seems to follow Shammai. But the Talmud?

Comment: The question on the Rambam seems more interesting. Why is he holding like Beit Shammai?

Comment: There is a general rule that we hold like Beit Hillel and not like Beit Shammei with 6 exceptions, and this is not one of them. So the question is why the Rambam holds like the latter, not how we hold

Comment: I still don't know why you are so fixated on this subject.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "according to the Talmud." The gemara there doesn't give a psak. So presumably it should be the default rule that the halakhah is like Biet Hillel. But when the Rambam gives a psak he isn't "arguing" on the talmud; he is (ostensibly at least) telling you what he thinks the Talmud's conclusion is.

Comment: By "according to the Talmud", I mean according to the Halakhah.

Comment: @Ootsutsuki "_By 'according to the Talmud', I mean according to the Halakhah._" So why not state so explicitly in the question?